# missing "linux/ext2_fs.h" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

O/S : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

While attempting to compile the e2undel source, gcc is complaining about :

e2undel.h:9:27: fatal error: linux/ext2_fs.h: No such file or directory

The file most certainly does not exist on this file system, and I an not quite sure how to resolve the issue or where to get the requisite package.

Comment: Try installing the `linux-headers` package.  The `apt-file` tool is a great way to answer the question "which package contains the file I am looking for".

Comment: @tadman: I think that's a different issue.  In that question, the file is present but the code does not compile.  Here it is not present at all.

Comment: Some of the suggested fixes involve removing that include and replacing it with others, as per the mailing list discussion where there's frustration people are still using it. Does this still fail on Ubuntu 20?

Comment: Nate ; Thanks for the quick responses. Installing linux-headers did not make any difference.

Comment: tadman : I DID see references to getting away from using the kernel headers when compiling in userspace, but wanted to keep as close to the original distribution as possible. Been searching this issue for a few days now, but still no definitive answers.

Comment: Nate: I may have spoken too soon. Turns out that the apt-get for the kernel headers failes because it wanted more detailed version and CPU info to install

Comment: You might have better luck building Ubuntu's 0.82-1.1 version from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/e2undel/0.82-1.1) because it doesn't use linux/ext2_fs.h. It uses headers from the e2fslibs-dev package instead. There might still be problems building for Ubuntu 16.04 since the last Ubuntu release that included the binary packages was 14.04.